# How can I avoid a "no match" error in this C shell script?

Tags: csh

Consider the following C shell script:

```
set MYVAR = "a='str.*' -p -10"
set output = `echo "$MYVAR" | sed 's/-p -[0-9]\+/-p -100/g'`
echo "$output"
```

When sourced from the shell, I get the error `echo: no match`. What changes can I make to the script to avoid the error? I tried adding ":q" and using a Perl one liner but haven't found an elegant solution.

Comment: Why is there a Perl tag on this question?

Comment: Because I tried adding a Perl one liner but couldn't find one that works.

Comment: Please show the Perl code that you tried

Comment: What is the script supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky because you have both ".*" {which would glob for files} and a single quote in MYVAR {which means you can't use the ' to say interpret literally}
The best I can think of here is to replace the double quote in MYVAR with single quotes in which case everything should work. Your sed line doesn't work. But that is not the problem. I replaced the sed to mimic what I think you are trying to do.

So:

```
- set MYVAR = 'a="str.*" -p -10'
- echo $MYVAR
  echo: No match. #as expected because you need to put it in double quotes
- echo "$MYVAR"
  a="str.*" -p -10
- set output = `echo "$MYVAR" | sed 's/-p -10/-p -100/g'`
- echo $output
  echo: No match. #Reason same as before
- echo "$output"
  a="str.*" -p -100
```